# Docker send build context fail - Connection forcibly closed

Tags: windows, docker, firewall, gateway

I have been having issues when trying to build a docker images from a client.
I am using the "docker --host x.x.x.x build" command. The build start to be sent and fails few second after with the following error:

> time="2017-08-11T09:43:27+01:00" level=error msg="Can't add file \\?\E:\folder\master\workspace\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3.nupkg to tar: io: read/write on closed pipe"
>   time="2017-08-11T09:43:27+01:00" level=error msg="Can't close tar writer: io: read/write on closed pipe" 
>   error during connect: Post http://x.x.x.x:2375/v1.27/build?buildargs=%7B%22CONFIGURATION%22%3A%22live%22%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&nocache=1&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=project&target=&ulimits=null: 
>   read tcp y.y.y.y:52954->x.x.x.x:2375: 
>   wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was located in the Gateway firewall. The process was trying to send Newtonsoft nuget package in tar file (as per the logs) and the firewall detected it as a Ransomware so it was closing the connection.
You can allow the specific file in the firewall to make it work.